# How can i generate a script that contain configuration of capabilities and all the setup for my tests to avoid writing a setup method in each class

Tags: testing, automation, protractor, testng, appium

In order to automate test cases with java using testNG and Appium :

- How can i generate a script that contain common configuration of capabilities and all the setup for my tests to avoid writing a setup method in each class and run it with the same manner as when i run appium by npm with protractor scripts

This is the following code i use to run appium with protractor by console :

```
appium --default-capabilities '{"app":"safari","browserName":"safari","appium-version":"1.5.1","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"9.3","deviceName":"iPad Air","nativeInstrumentsLib":true}' --command-timeout "0" --pre-launch --nodeconfig "/Users/me/nodeconfig.json" --launch-timeout "180000"
```

- Another question : How can i use only console with testng test and eliminate the use of eclipse IDE as i'm doing with protractor all my test written with console in vi mode in Mac ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For java using testNG and Appium:

create a base class where you will set the appium driver with all the capabilities and than extend this base class to get the appium driver.

u can also do this by invoking that class constructor. U can go through this sites to get idea:

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/constant-variables/

http://blog.xebia.in/2016/01/11/Design-Patterns-in-Selenium-Automation-Part1-POM/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what i understand from site (1)  it's a class in the same project? and we can we put it more general with design pattern that we run from console like appium configuration from site (2)?
I'll take a big focus on the second site it looks very interesting ;) ^^

Comment: actually, i do my test in a java project. There, all capabilities and driver set up is done in one class. when i run my test from another class, i just get the appium driver from that class by using testng @BeforeTest annotation.

Comment: Cool, this is right. And you are using an IDE let's say Eclipse? 
Is there a way that we run all testng by console after running appium, because we have to prepare things for jenkins (i didn't use it before, it will be my 1st time but i think that scripts in console are recommended for protractor so that i'm asking if there is a similar way with testNG in console) or i am confusing between them?

Comment: u can run ur java project through a shell script and in jenkins, u just give the location of ur shell script, jenkins than run ur java project through that shell script..:)